# Declaration with argument length zero in R

Tags: r, declaration

I have the following statement:

```
if(Estatu== "INF"){
 MIN <- 5
 } else if (length(Estatu)==0) { 
 MIN <- 0
 }
```

It's very simple, but `Estatu` sometimes has `INF` and other times it's an empty value `(character 0)`.

I have two problems:

1. When the value is `character(0)`, it indicates the following error:

   ```
   Error in if (Estatu== "INF") { : 
     argument has zero length
   ```

   I would like it not to give me an error because I have already put below that the value can be zero length.
2. When the declaration is repeated and the value is "0" instead of putting the value `0` in `MIN`, the data of the declaration that has been executed before remains in `MIN`. I put in MIN the previous value, the result of the previous execution of this statement.

What I can do?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What about the case where the length is > 0, but the value is not equal to `"INF"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `length` expression as the first one so that it gets evaluated before anything else

```
Estatu <- character(0)
if(length(Estatu) == 0) 0 else if(Estatu == "INF") 5
[1] 0
```

Comment: It solved both problems for me at once. Now it's perfect, thank you very much.